# Inserting multiple records with unique key per insert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a table `offices`. On the insert page of the app, I have two textboxes for the office name and the type of office, and a button that says `Add Office`. I use jQuery to duplicate the two textboxes, so the user can insert more than one office at a time. A user may put in an office name and a type, hit `Add Office`, insert a couple of more offices on the same page, and hit `Submit`.

I'd like to use a `group_by` query to group together offices that were created at the same time. I found a way for each insert row to have a unique key. I want the rows for a group of offices to share the same unique key. Is this possible?

Comment: I really don't understand who's going about downrating questions all the time! There is nothing wrong with this question! I'm going to uprate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller under the action, you can create a random number and have a third field on your table that accepts the unique key. This unique key value would be the random number.

`@unique_key = rand[99999999999]`

However, this approach does allow a small 1/99999999999 chance that you would create the same `unique_key` value as another office. Instead, you may want to create a random hash instead to reduce the possibility of creating the duplicate.

`@unique_key = SecureRandom.hex`

To make this even less likely, you could do

`@unique_key = "#{SecureRandom.hex}#{SecureRandom.hex}"`

which would still technically be possible, but extremely unlikely.

This example is if you're using simple_form. You would want to modify to your own specifics

`<%= f.input :unique_key, :as => :hidden, :input_html => {:value => @unique_key} %>`

Comment: Oh, don't forget to `add_index` in your migration to ensure that the `unique_key` is index which will better optimized on your database.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have `group_by` in ActiveRecord queries. You *do* have `group`, but that's if you want to make sums and counts on groups of rows, which I don't think is the case here.

Instead you can use `group_by` on the returned results. To clarify, *it won't be part of the query generated*, but it will "group" your results "by" certain criteria, like a unique key, resulting in a Hash, where each entry in the Hash will have an array of offices with the same unique key:

`Office.where(...some condition...).group_by(&:my_unique_key_field_name)`

Or just:

`Office.all.group_by(&:my_unique_key_field_name)`

Please take note of kobaltz answer for generating the unique key and consider uprating it if you found it useful.

Blessings.